# Google App Engine program Recovery

Tags: google-app-engine

A friend of mine messed up his php website and accidentally deployed the bad code to the website. Is there a way to recover to the last working deployment instance?

Answer (score 2):

If new code was deployed with a new version number, you may be able to set the previous version as default, if it was not deleted.

If new code was deployed with the same version number, it replaced the previous code - there is no way to restore it.

Typically, version control for your source code takes care of this - you cannot rely on a production environment for restoring previous versions.

Comment: Exactly right -- and Google Cloud Repositories, https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-repositories/docs/ , are Google Cloud Platform's little helpers to make source code version control easy and seamless and extra-precious to you (for example, by enabling the Cloud Debugger... though that doesn't currently apply to PHP).